# When using createrepo can I place rpms in multiple directories?

Tags: yum, rpm, repository

When I use the `createrepo` command can I place RPMs (within the base dir) in multiple directories (think hierarchical) and still have yum recursively look at all the RPMs the directories within the base dir?

Example:

```
createrepo /srv/my/repo 
/srv/my/repo/vendor1/package1/first.rpm
/srv/my/repo/vendor1/package2/first.rpm

/srv/my/repo/vendor2/package1/third.rpm
```

I ask because I placed one of the RPMs in a directory, did a `createrepo --update` and a `yum clean all` yet it still didn't pick it up. Now I'm wondering if it needs to be in a flat file structure instead of hierarchical structure?

Comment: when I add repo I use the entire path to repo file. I'm sure you need to use the actual filename in createrepo command unless it has a way to include all repos from a top directory. Try doing it one at a time to see if that works.

Comment: @unixmiah: Hi, when you say 'entire path to repo file', do you mean the base dir? Because I found that if I place all my RPM file inside `/srv/my/repo` they are successfully picked up by yum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that no, `createrepo` cannot recursively walk a directory tree. You therefore have to flatten your repo's directory structure. I usually use this type of looping construct in my repo building script.

```
destdir="/path/to/my/yum-repos/Fedora/14"
for arch in i386 x86_64 noarch; do
  printf "\n\n==== creating repo: %-50s [%-s]\n" $destdir $arch
  pushd ${destdir}/${arch} >/dev/null 2>&1
  createrepo -dp .
  popd >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: For future reference, the answer to this question may be different now. I just tried running createrepo 0.9.9 on a RHEL7 system and found that it is walking through and finding PRMs in subdirectories, no flattening required. Another user has posted a similar response as an answer to this question

Comment: This is no longer true.  Looking at the way fedora lays out it file structure you will find that RPMs are in a directory corresponding to the RPM's first letter.  http://mirrors.xmission.com/fedora/linux/updates/33/Everything/x86_64/Packages/.  While the `repodata` database is a sibling to `Packages`.  http://mirrors.xmission.com/fedora/linux/updates/33/Everything/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

This thread, and my own anecdotal evidence, suggest that yum createrepo will traverse sub directories and you do not need to flatten.

http://lists.baseurl.org/pipermail/yum/2013-December/024061.html

> that would appear to be what's happening based on a test i just
>   ran. i created a new directory, /usr/local/repob/pkgs/b/, and copied
>   into it all fedora 19 rpm files starting with the letter "b". then
>   i ran "createrepo" from higher up the directory structure with:
>
> # createrepo /usr/local/repob
>
> and it appeared to create a new local yum repository just fine by
>   recursively searching the entire directory structure. i verified that
>   by creating a quick /etc/yum.repos.d/ .conf file for the new repo and
>   using "repoquery" to list its packages, and they were all there.
>
> so it appears that createrepo, by default, recursively scans
>   the "/path/to/rpms/" directory, but that doesn't seem to be
>   mentioned anywhere in the man page, and i think that's a useful
>   bit of information to know.

Comment: This is new behavior, prior versions did not do this in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

you can if you use a symlink in the same directory where the /repodata is.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a recursive `createrepo` command would not populate `repoData/` if any RPMS are corrupt.

Check the size of RPMs with `ll` to make sure they are not empty files.

My file structure

```
com/
example/
  dir1/*.rpms
  dir2/*.rpms
```

```
sudo createrepo ./com/example
```

Answer (score 0):

`createrepo` version 0.9.9 (maybe before) goes into subdirectories.